# Rolling metrics with a part of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this extract of a dataframe with several fictional transactions on Google Stock. My main goal is to calculate some metrics just before each transaction. For example, i have achieved to calculate the "Net_position","Total_Nominal", "Total_number_operations" and "Weighted average price"

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':[pd.datetime(2020,1,1),pd.datetime(2020,1,3),pd.datetime(2020,1,4),pd.datetime(2020,1,5),pd.datetime(2020,1,6),pd.datetime(2020,1,7),pd.datetime(2020,1,8),pd.datetime(2020,1,8)],
                   'TradeID':['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08'],
                   'Security': ['GOOGLE', 'GOOGLE', 'GOOGLE', 'GOOGLE', 'GOOGLE','GOOGLE','GOOGLE','GOOGLE'], 
                   'ID': ['ID001', 'ID002', 'ID003', 'ID004', 'ID005','ID006','ID007','ID008'], 
                   'BSType': ['B', 'S', 'B', 'B', 'B','S','S','S'], 
                   'Price':[105.901,106.969,106.716,107.037,107.038,107.136,107.007,107.25],
                   'Quantity':[1000000,-300000,300000,7500000,100000,-100000,-400000,-7800000]
                  })

df['Volume'] = df['Quantity']*df['Price']
df['abs_Volume'] = df['Volume'].abs()
df['abs_quantity']=df['Quantity'].abs()

from pandas.core.window.rolling import _Rolling_and_Expanding
def weighted_average(x):
    d = []
    d.append(x['abs_Volume'].sum()/x['abs_quantity'].sum())
    return pd.Series(d, index=['wavg'])
_Rolling_and_Expanding.weighted_average = weighted_average


df=df.set_index('day')
calculations_holdings=df.groupby(["Security","ID"])['Volume'].rolling('60D',closed='left').sum().reset_index().sort_values(["day","Security","ID"]).rename(columns={'Volume':'Net Position'})
calculations_operaciones=df.groupby(["Security","ID"])['Volume'].rolling('60D',closed='left').count().reset_index().sort_values(["day","Security","ID"]).rename(columns={'Volume':'Total_number_operations'})
calculations_cantidad=df.groupby(["Security","ID"])['Quantity'].rolling('60D',closed='left').sum().reset_index().sort_values(["day","Security","ID"]).rename(columns={'Quantity':'Total_Nominal'})
calculations_precios=df.groupby(["Security","ID"]).rolling(window='60d',closed='left').weighted_average()
calculations_precios=calculations_precios['wavg'].reset_index().sort_values(["day","Security","ID"]).rename(columns={0:'Weigthed_average_price'})
df=df.reset_index()
dfs= [df.set_index(["day","Security","ID"]) for df in [df,calculations_holdings, calculations_operaciones, calculations_cantidad,calculations_precios]]
df_def=pd.concat(dfs,axis=1).reset_index().drop(['abs_Volume', 'abs_quantity'], axis=1)
```

Now my goal is to calculate more or less the same metrics but dividing between the "B" and the "S". Also i would like to calculate the weighted average price considering only the "B" transactions.

The output should be something like this:

```
df_def['Number_operations_B']=[0,1,1,2,3,4,4,4]
df_def['Number_operations_S']=[0,0,1,1,1,1,2,3]
df_def['Nominal_B']=[0,1000000,1000000,1300000,8800000,8900000,8900000,8900000]
df_def['Nominal_S']=[0,0,-300000,-300000,-300000,-300000,-400000,-800000]
df_def['weighted_price_B']=['nan',105.901,105.901,106.089,106.896,106.898,106.898,106.898]
df_def

day Security     ID TradeID BSType    Price  Quantity       Volume  \
0 2020-01-01   GOOGLE  ID001      01      B  105.901   1000000  105901000.0   
1 2020-01-03   GOOGLE  ID002      02      S  106.969   -300000  -32090700.0   
2 2020-01-04   GOOGLE  ID003      03      B  106.716    300000   32014800.0   
3 2020-01-05   GOOGLE  ID004     04      B  107.037   7500000  802777500.0   
4 2020-01-06   GOOGLE  ID005      05      B  107.038    100000   10703800.0   
5 2020-01-07   GOOGLE  ID006      06      S  107.136   -100000  -10713600.0   
6 2020-01-08   GOOGLE  ID007      07      S  107.007   -400000  -42802800.0   
7 2020-01-08   GOOGLE  ID008      08      S  107.250  -7800000 -836550000.0   

   Net Position  Total_number_operations  Total_Nominal  \
0           NaN                      NaN            NaN   
1   105901000.0                      1.0      1000000.0   
2    73810300.0                      2.0       700000.0   
3   105825100.0                      3.0      1000000.0   
4   908602600.0                      4.0      8500000.0   
5   919306400.0                      5.0      8600000.0   
6   908592800.0                      6.0      8500000.0   
7   865790000.0                      7.0      8100000.0   

   Weigthed_average_price  Number_operations_B  Number_operations_S  \
0                     NaN                    0                    0   
1              105.901000                    1                    0   
2              106.147462                    1                    1   
3              106.254063                    2                    1   
4              106.899341                    3                    1   
5              106.900848                    4                    1   
6              106.903376                    4                    2   
7              106.907649                    4                    3   

   Nominal_B  Nominal_S weighted_price_B  
0          0          0              nan  
1    1000000          0          105.901  
2    1000000    -300000          105.901  
3    1300000    -300000          106.089  
4    8800000    -300000          106.896  
5    8900000    -300000          106.898  
6    8900000    -400000          106.898  
7    8900000    -800000          106.898
```

¿How can i calculate these last five columns? I do not know how to calculate these metrics considering only part of the dataframe ("B" Trades or "S" trades)

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: @ApplePie I forgot to includ the explicit question. Thanks for the observation.